# What is the name of this search term popularity component?

Tags: search, components, popularity

If you look at [SharpCrafters](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), the front page has a cool component that shows how popular certain search terms are, with larger text for more popular terms. I've seen this around the web in different places, especially blogs. **What is this called in general, and what specific implementations exist?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [Tag Cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_Cloud).